# How do i center an HTML DIV with logo on the left?

Tags: html, css, layout, center, graphical-logo

i want to center a div called #top_menu

```
<div id="top_menu">This is the menu and it is in the middle of the page</div>
```

CSS-Code:

```
#top_menu { margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; ... }
```

To the left of the top menu should be a logo (#logo)

This is what i have so far:

```
#logo { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px; width: 200px }
```

**Now comes the problem**

If i have a browser window that is smaller than 800px the center div overlays the logo div. It would be nice if there are scrollbars instead. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance! Freddi

Comment: Could you create an example at http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: To see it in action: beta.sportpreis24.de

Comment: Thanks. Now where should the logo appear? On the left side of the menu, outside of those 600px or inside but pushing the menu to the right?

Comment: It should appear always on the top left (top: 0px, left:0px;) not pushing the menu to the right. Outside of those 600px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

```
#top_menu{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
}

#logo { 
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    background:white url(logo.png) no-repeat 0 0
}
```

Now your divs will not overlap when window size is smaller.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/WV8q7/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this (in css) :

```
#top_menu { overflow: auto; }
```

You must have your logo tag inside the div tag, of course.

Comment: okay, now the logo is inside the box. i tried to { position: absolute; left: 0} nothing. logo still inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
#logo
{
    float: left;
}
```

AND

```
#top_menu
{
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    height:29px;
    width: 602px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="logo"><img src="<?=site_url('img/logo.jpg')?>" /></div>

        <div id="top_menu">



            <ul id="top_links">
                <li><a href="<?=site_url()?>">Startseite</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=site_url('static/impressum')?>">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```